# Using cin to traverse an array

Tags: c++

my question is: do I need to use cin to traverse and test values in an array for certain condition or can I simply just test values without using cin.

Example:

//is this necessary?

```
while (word[i]!='\0'){
 cin >> word[i];
 if (word[i] == 'K')
   cout <<"Letter 'K' is in array << ends;
 i++;
 cin >> word[i];
}
```

...or can I just do this:

```
while (word[i]!='\0'){
 if (word[i] == 'K')
   cout <<"Letter 'K' is in array << ends;
 i++;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `cin >> word[i];` does?

Comment: What is `word`?

Comment: it seems to be char array (C string) from null terminated check. :)

Answer (score 2):

cin is an operator used for reading input.

For this code to work..

```
   while (word[i]!='\0'){
 if (word[i] == 'K')
   cout <<"Letter 'K' is in array << ends;
 i++;
}
```

You already require a array with name "word" which you probably have to get either from user as input or by giving the value to the array directly.

If you want the user to enter the array values, you can use cin operator in a loop before the above mentioned code so that the array "word" gets filled.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and plain answer:

> No. You got it all wrong. `cin` doesn't have anything to do with array
>   traversal.

`cin` is actually used to read the user input. If you're interested in taking keyboard input, save it in array and then traverse it, then you should use `cin` (to take input, not to traverse).

For simple traversal the second code snippet should work fine if `word` is a null terminated and pre-populated character array(C string).